# Xcode Storyboard layout anomaly, bug or something else?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I"m seeing an anomaly with the storyboard in my project and not sure if it's a bug or something else I'm doing wrong. Within a UIViewController, an element may or may not start shifting its position to the left and down by one each time the project is opened. It doesn't happen everytime the project is opened. It's not limited to any particular type of control. These screenshots of are a UIScrollView, but it happens on UITableView, UITextView, etc.

I'm not using autolayout. I haven't filed a bug report yet.

thanks for anyones help!

[image: ok here]

[image: minus 1 to the left]

[image: minus 2 to the left]

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: Why are these views shifting on thier own? What is there in my question that is ambiguous?

Comment: There is _no_ question in your question. That's why I'm asking you what the question is. There is just a statement that you're seeing a bug. What do you want from Stack Overflow?

Comment: I've reworded the question.

Comment: I still don't see any question.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce this. The problem is the autoresizing settings. (Other things in the screenshots, such as the fact that this is a scrollview and that it is ridiculously huge, are red herrings; you can see the same phenomenon with a small plain vanilla UIView.) You can certainly call that a bug if you like, and I would definitely recommend reporting it to Apple, but the situation is also a bit artificial, because autoresizing is barely ever used any more, and almost never in the storyboard. So yes, it's a bug, but it probably doesn't affect any real people.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with my older views which are on autoresizing. Didn't found any solution yet else than to convert to auto layout

Comment: Same problem here. Removing the stretch wasn't the solution for me. Now, having my MacBook and Xcode opened all the time. Yesterday Xcode crashed and when re-opening, all the view moved again. Really ridiculous that they haven't solved it yet!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the horizontal and vertical stretchable properties of autoresizing and handle the stretch in subviews then you will be able to fix this bug. I have tried this hack and it was not changing the frame on quitting and re-opening the **Xcode**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks so much. That is working for me. Also... from Apple: "This sounds like a known problem in Xcode, though there’s currently no solution and no known workaround.". I have filed a bug report.