# Xcode 14 - The frame of subviews automatically changing

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I have a container view inside main main view of `UIViewController` which is in storyboard. The **containerView** have multiple subviews which further have textfields and labels inside them.

All of this hierarchy is in **autoresizing** model.

Now what is wrong here is that whenever I close **Xcode** and come back to those views, the subview frames automatically get disturbs and normally go in negative like if it is on 0 from y axis it will now be -2 or -3.

It is happening in multiple controllers and mostly on the **storyboards** which have more than 7-8 controllers. **Auto layout** resolves this issue but due to a lot of views it would be a time taking task.

Any suggestions to resolve this problem without converting to **auto layout**?

**Edit:**
I have reduced the number of controllers in storyboards  as well but it didn't effected and the issue is still appearing

Comment: Are you observing incorrect frames only in Interface Builder or does it affect the running app as well?

Comment: It effects the running app as well

Comment: same issue described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74982560/xcode-storyboard-layout-anomaly-bug-or-something-else ... check the comments

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, if the stretchable properties of autoresizing are removed and the stretch is handled in subviews then this issue do not happen. I have tried this hack and it was not changing the frame on quoting and reopening the Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. Removing the stretch wasn't the solution for me. Now, having my MacBook and Xcode opened all the time. Yesterday Xcode crashed and when re-opening, all the view moved again. Really ridiculous that they haven't solved it yet!